# How to automatically post a tweet on twitter

Tags: twitter

I am working on a site where users can submit data. Is it possible to set up an automated system such that a tweet goes out every time a new data set is received?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's possible through their own API: http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/22554648/FrontPage

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start is the [Twitter API](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/22554648/FrontPage).

Answer (score 0):

Using Abraham's Oauth library in your application and once you have verified/cleaned user import use the variables in an if statement and then call the library and post a tweet. i have a similar set up for adding films i've seen into a database and it tweets a rating everytime.

I can provide coding example (PHP) later if you need further help.